# How to create a global lookup table in React that is quickly accessible across components?

Tags: reactjs, global-variables, react-component, lookup-tables

I am trying to convert a web-app from vanilla JS to react. The web-app has what I call a color Manager which is basically a lookup table that allows the app to look up a color that has not been used yet, to assign it to various elements located in different components. Since I do not know much about React, yet, I was wondering whether someone in the community has an idea of how to do this optimally. I'd rather not use callbacks to pass the information from a single child where a new color assignment happened to the parent to then pass the change in the color lookup table down to the other children again.

Here's a screenshot of the vanilla JS web-app so you can get an idea of the different components and the color changes that need to be made in these components 'parallelly'.

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKoAO.jpg)

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you are looking for some form of state management. Naturally I would recommend [Redux](https://redux.js.org/). But that might be an overkill for your app (Not familiar with all info about it.) In that case, you might take a look at [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

What these 2 modules do is keep a global state which can be injected into any component, child or parent, as long as they are all inside some form of a **Provider**.

Take a look at a simple [example](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/react-context-in-5-minutes/) between day/night global variable switch, which can then be accessed from child or parent components as well

Comment: @RobertRoessler I've added an example tutorial for React Context. Hope it helps you

Comment: great! This s exactly what I need. Only one last follow-up question: Is there a chance to access the context data also in the methods of consumer components?

Comment: You can invoke access to context data in any React Component, again, if it is properly structured to be nested inside a Provider. I do not know your exact case per se, but I am pretty sure you can achieve what you want with a few examples of React Context. Start small, and then make it more complex, do not try to figure it out all at once, it can be daunting.